# How to turn multiple columns into numeric for specific columns only using a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, numeric, gsub

Beginner here: I have a dataframe with multiple columns that are currently strings that contain a $-sign and spaces and I want to turn them into numeric. My dataframe looks like this:

```
Name  Col_x_1    Company  Col_x_2  Start_Year  End_Year  Col_x_3
asd   $841 392   Test     $31 000  1902        1933      0
kfj   0          Test_2   0        1933        1954      $10 000
ale   $200 000   Test_3   0        1988        1999      0
...
```

I am currently using the following code to loop this through for the columns named `Col_x_` as they are all named the same in ascending order:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Col_x_"), ~gsub("\\$", "", .) %>% 
                  as.numeric())
         )
```

however, this only gives me NAs as the as.numeric() does not work. Does anyone know how I can fix this code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You also need to remove the spaces, so `31 000` should be `31000`.

Comment: How do I incorporate this into the code @MartinGal?

Comment: `gsub("\\$|\\s", "", .)` should work. This removes all `$` and all spaces in the target columns.

Comment: You could also use `gsub("\\D", "", .)` which would remove any non-digit character.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Col_x_"), ~ str_remove_all(.x, "[^0-9]"))) %>%
  type_convert()

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Name  Col_x_1 Company Col_x_2 Start_Year End_Year Col_x_3
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 asd    841392 Test      31000       1902     1933       0
2 kfj         0 Test_2        0       1933     1954   10000
3 ale    200000 Test_3        0       1988     1999       0
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions in the comments, you could also use the convenience functions of {readr}, e. g.:

```
library(readr)

my_locale <- locale(grouping_mark = " ")
```

effect:

```
> parse_number("$12 235", locale = my_locale)
[1] 12235
```